# Is there a way to get view model intellisense if I am using Typescript and Angular?

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio

(using Visual Studio and Angular)

Example:

Suppose I have a typescript controller like this:

```
class MyController {
  public widget: IWidget;
}
```

An now I'm coding my HTML view:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as vm" >
  {{vm.widget. <--- would love intellisense right here
```

Is there any way to get that in VS? (I'm using VS 2015 pro, update 1)

Comment: Not the answer you want BUT Web Storm supports this.

Comment: Well that figures!  Not surprising -- Jetbrains makes pretty awesome stuff.